# router.push() vuejs не отправляет на главную

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть сайт, есть два разных типа пользователей, для одних используется /login /register, для других /profile/login /profile/register

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/profile',
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    root:  '/profile',
    routes: [{
        path: '/register',
        name: 'register',
        component: Register,
        meta: {
            auth: false
        }
    },{
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
    },{
        path: '/',
        name: 'user',
        component: User,
        meta: {
            auth: {
                forbiddenRedirect: '/login'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Если клиент заходит на /profile его редиректит на /profile/login, но как сделать так, чтобы если человек уже залогинен его кидало на /profile из /profile/login я ума не приложу.

Если вставлять в компоненте vue.js this.$router.push('/'); Меня редиректит на туже страницу, где я нахожусь, а не на /profile.

Подскажите, что тут можно сделать, где я накосячил

Comment: Так может, всё-таки, надо `this.$router.push('/profile');`?

Comment: @AlexSazonov тогда путь строится /profile/profile я хз как так

Comment: Ну если ещё не поздно, попробуй переписать роут без использования вот этих вот root и прочей красоты. Я даже не знаю, какую мысль подкинуть. Никогда не делал так.

Comment: @AlexSazonov без рутов и бейзов не работало вообще))))

Comment: Используйте имена маршрутов: `router.push({ name: '...'})`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов тоже пробовал, не работает

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема именно в поле `root` кроется. Что-то мне подсказывает...

Comment: @AlexSazonov может быть, но тогда другое падает

Comment: Тогда вопрос: а пользователи, для которых `используется /login /register` обрабатываются другим маршрутизатором?

Comment: @РустамГимранов да, там вообще php, а не vue =)

Comment: @РустамГимранов отрабатывает

Comment: @РустамГимранов vuex и все, не считая axios

Comment: Если сторонние плагины авторизации не используются и отрабатывает  `forbiddenRedirect` без кода тут нечего сказать.

Comment: @РустамГимранов 
        this.$router.push('//'); вот такое порно помогло